# ! LaTeX Error: Unicode character − (U+2212) not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: errors, unicode

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{var} % variance "operator"
\DeclareMathOperator{\mse}{mse}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Probability and inference}
\section{means and variances of conditional distributions}
The following result 
\begin{equation}
\var(u) = E(\var(u|v)) + \var(E(u|v))
\end{equation}
can be derived by expanding the terms on the right side
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:means_variances}
\begin{aligned}
E(\var(u|v)) + \var(E(u|v)) & = E(E(u^2|v)-(E(u|v))^2)+E((E(u|v))^2)-(E(E(u|v)))^2 \\                & = E(u^2)-E((E(u|v))^2)+E((E(u|v))^2)-(E(u))^2        \\                & =E(u^2)-(E(u))^2=\var(u).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The above Identity %$\ref{eqn:means_variances}$
,along with
\begin{equation}
E(u) = E(E(u|v)),
\end{equation}
also hold if $u$ is a vector, in which case $E(u)$ is a vector and $\var(u)$
a matrix.
\subsection{Transformation of variables}
In one dimension, we commonly use the logarithm to transform the parameter space from $(0,\infty)$ to $(−\infty,\infty)$. When working with parameters defined on the open unit interval, $(0, 1)$, we often use the logistic transformation:
\begin{equation}
logit(u) = log\left(\frac{u}{1-u}\right),
\end{equation}
whose inverse transformation is
\begin{equation}
logit^{-1}(v) = \frac{e^v}{1+e^v}.
\end{equation}
Another common choice is the probit transformation, $\Phi^{−1}(u)$, where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cumulative distribution function, to transform from $(0, 1)$ to $(−\infty,\infty)$.
\end{document}
```

I really don't get the meaning of the error I get

```
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character − (U+2212)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Comment: use a ascii hyphen-minus - not −

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unicode-math` package accepts that character. You can load a font that supports it, through, for example, `fontsetup`.

An alternative that works with PDFTeX is to add the command:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\ensuremath{-}}
```

The above turns U+2212 into an alias for a math-mode `-`.

Finally, you could do a search-and-replace from `−` (U+2212) to `-` (hyphen-minus).

Comment: yes +1, I'd wondered about saying that, but decided to keep to most direct cause of the error, but you are probably right to give the other half of the story too.

Comment: Why `\ensuremath`? You want rather to *ensure that the character only appears in math mode*, which is quite different; in order to achieve this you might say `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\mathbin-}`.

Comment: @egreg In this case, so that the Unicode minus character does not render as a hyphen in text mode. If that is not a concern, you could drop that command.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a normal keyboard `-` so

```
$\Phi^{-1}(u)$
      %^%%
```

not

```
$\Phi^{−1}(u)$
      %^%%
```